# How to improve a question that isn't being answered?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

I asked this question ([How to reformat/reindent all the source files in a given directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98164/how-to-reformat-reindent-all-the-source-files-in-a-given-directory)) which – I admit – at the beginning was not very well defined, but, with the help of the comments left by people, I have improved a bit.

The problem is that it seems that the question still isn't getting much attention and there aren't any interesting answers.

My question is: how can I improve that question so that it gets more attention and hopefully a good answer?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions

Answer (score 3):

Tacking a bounty on it always helps!

One thing you can do is keep updating your question with the results of your research. What tools have you tried so far? Did they get you the results you wanted?

Making your question be a sort of journal of what you've been searching for over time will just keep improving it and giving people more information over time, and a crucial bump to get it back onto the home page.

Something I tend to do is do like:

> Here are some of the things I've tried so far:

at the bottom of my question, and then I just keep adding things to it that might or might not have worked.

Answer (score 2):

"Pictures are worth a thousand words".

Think about the before and after - show a good example of what your current view from *Nautilus* - and show another picture (maybe crafted in Pinta for example) how you might want it too look.

If you have been looking at this for sometime, give some thoughts to what stuff you have been looking at, blogs, websites etc.  Add this to the question. For example you been looking at source trees - which ones? example projects?  Try to make the question as specific as possible.

It may be worth trying to restrict your question to more specific related areas e.g. a scripting tool, a compiled language tool.

If a question is getting relatively low views, then you need to be thinking about regularly editing the question to bump it to the top of the activity list.

If the question is important to you, you may wish to consider offering a small bounty - you'll be surprised how this would galvanise someone to spend a little more effort answering you question.